# How to pass Client-Side variables to Server-Side Password Protection

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to add some user authentication to a web application I have. When the user clicks the loadorder button a prompt should show up and request a password. I am getting the employeeNumber from the load order button and comparing it with Sql database.

```vb
Public Shared Function SfGetUserPassword(ByVal UserID As String) As System.Data.DataTable

        Dim Database As New ACGCommon.Database(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connectionString").ConnectionString)
        Database.AddParameter("@UserID", UserID)
        Return Database.GetDataSet("data", "gcshopfloor_SfGetEmployeePassword").Tables(0)

    End Function
```

This calls my stored procedure in SQL

```vb
 Private Function CheckPassword(employeeNumber As String, password As String) As Boolean
        Dim dt As DataTable = Users.SfGetUserPassword(tbEmployeeNumber.Text.Trim)
        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            If row("UserId").ToString() = employeeNumber AndAlso row("SfUserPassword").ToString() = password Then
                ' EmployeeNumber and password match, return true
                Return True
            End If
        Next
        ' EmployeeNumber and/or password do not match, return false
        Return False
    End Function
    '*********************************************************************************
    '
    '*********************************************************************************
    Private Sub btnSubmitPassword_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmitPassword.Click
        Dim employeeNumber As String = Request.QueryString("tbemployeeNumber")
        Dim password As String = Request.QueryString("SfUserPassword")
        Dim isPasswordCorrect As Boolean = CheckPassword(employeeNumber, password) ' implement your password check logic here
        Response.Write(isPasswordCorrect.ToString().ToLower()) ' send the password check result back to the client-side code
    End Sub
```

This is my password check and submit password button. This will take the SfUserpassword and employee number checking it in the database and return true or false.

My Javascript is what I need help on. When the btnLoadOrder button is clicked I want the password prompt to appear. Correct password can move on and incorrect, keep trying. If the user leaves the page and comes back, I also want to prompt for the password as well. Currently I can't get the javascript to get the password value and pass it back to the server side. Any thoughts?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
const loadOrderButton = document.getElementById("<%= btnLoadOrder.ClientID %>");
loadOrderButton.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const employeeNumber = document.getElementById("<%= tbEmployeeNumber.ClientID %>").value;
    console.log(employeeNumber); // you can do something with the employeeNumber value here
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent the default behavior of the button
    document.getElementById("passwordPanel").style.display = "block";

    const submitPasswordButton = document.getElementById("<%= btnSubmitPassword.ClientID %>");
    submitPasswordButton.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const password = document.getElementById("<%= SfUserPassword.ClientID %>").value;
    console.log(SfUserPassword)


      const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              const response = this.responseText;
              if (response === "true") {
                  // password is correct, do something here
                  console.log("Password is correct!");
              } else {
                  // password is incorrect, show error message
                  document.getElementById("<%= lblPasswordError.ClientID %>").innerHTML = "Incorrect password";
                document.getElementById("<%= lblPasswordError.ClientID %>").style.display = "block";
              }
          }
      };
      xmlhttp.open("GET", "ShopFloorEntryNew.aspx.vb?UserID=" + employeeNumber + "&password=" + password, true);
      xmlhttp.send();

  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: How secure does it need to be? If it needs to be secure, e.g. the site deals with personally identifiable information, then the password check needs to be done on the server *and the server has to remember that* (somehow) so that the server can determine whether or not to allow further access, not with something client-side, which can always be faked. Also, please consider salting and hashing the passwords, such as described in [Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm).

Comment: Or, instead of re-inventing something which has been done already, strongly consider using ASP.NET Identity: [Introduction to ASP.NET Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity).

Comment: @AndrewMorton Hi, this is an internal site. It's not going very far. Super simple authentication is needed. It was never built for user auth so throwing this in is being a pain.

Comment: Why "ShopFloorEntryNew.aspx.vb?UserID=" ? .... instead of "ShopFloorEntryNew.aspx?UserID=" ... ??